# Cursor window allocation of 4096 kb failed

Tags: android, database, cursor

Usualy this error is happening when the cursor is not closed, but as for me i close it right way. What is the problem here?

Log:

```
    10-21 11:55:36.818 26541-26541/com.mycrosswod.crossfit E/CursorWindow: Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/com.mycrosswod.crossfit/databases/Crossfit' of size 4194304 due to error -12.
    10-21 11:55:36.843 26541-26541/com.mycrosswod.crossfit D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    10-21 11:55:36.843 26541-26541/com.mycrosswod.crossfit W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c681f8)
    10-21 11:55:36.863 26541-26541/com.mycrosswod.crossfit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycrosswod.crossfit/com.mycrosswod.crossfit.gui.WodsListActivity}: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 4096 kb failed. # Open Cursors=379 (# cursors opened by this proc=379)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycrosswod.crossfit/com.mycrosswod.crossfit.gui.WodsListActivity}: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 4096 kb failed. # Open Cursors=378 (# cursors opened by this proc=378)
```

Method:

```
ArrayList<WodForBuilder> wods = new ArrayList<WodForBuilder>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.WOD_TABLE,
            new String[]{"*"}, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        WodForBuilder wod = cursorToWodWithRound(cursor);
        wods.add(wod);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    if(cursor!=null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return wods;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

error code is -12 mean cursor leak, find all the Cusor query used in the project. check it is finally call close ();
recommend use 
              `try{
                  }catch(Exception e){
                  }finally{
                      cursor.close();
                  }`